# return null if one of field is not exist mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$check = "SELECT    up.quantity AS stockAble,
                    oh.quantity AS stockAsk

          FROM      stock_update up
          JOIN      orders oh
          ON        up.quantity > oh.quantity
          AND       up.package = oh.product_id

          WHERE     oh.reference_no = 12345 
          AND       up.location_id = 4                      
          ";
```

In the query, I select all the quantity of a package based on the reference no.

In the reference number of 12345, for instance, there are three rows of three products with each different quantity.

`Stock Ask` in `oh.quantity` From `orders`

```
  +---------------+--------------+------------+
    reference_no     product_id     quantity
  +---------------+--------------+------------+
      12345             1             30
      12345             2             10
      12345             3             20
```

However it needs to check if the quantity or the product which is asked is available in our table.

`Stock Available` in  `stock_update`

```
  +--------------+------------+
    product_id     quantity
  +--------------+------------+
         1             10
         2             15
         3             25
```

Based on the two tables above, there is one product which its available quantity is less than the quantity which is asked. It is in the row or in the product_id of `1`

If the condition is so, then I want the query return nothing or false.

The query will return true if only all the product and the quantity which is asked is available.

How to do that in the query I have tried above? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: What's the actual vs the expected result? Your query looks OK, except that you probably want to use `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: @fschmengler My query is still return two rows because one row is not exist. what I want is if one of the three is not exist, then I want the query no to turn any row.

Comment: Based on your sample data, your query returns `null` aka `no row`. except that you probably want to use `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: @RubahMalam I have tested it, it still return two rows.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to change the quantity. Please look at again at the table.

Answer (score 1):

After your comment, I get what you want and I think it's possible with some tricky subqueries but not sensible.

I'd rather perform two queries then:

1. find out if there is a case where `up.quantity < oh.quantity`

   ```
   SELECT 1
     FROM      stock_update up
     JOIN      orders oh
     ON        up.quantity < oh.quantity
     AND       up.package = oh.product_id

     WHERE     oh.reference_no = 12345 
     AND       up.location_id = 4
     LIMIT 1
   ```
2. if not (i.e. the previous query does not return any result), perform the original query

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But with the query above, now if all stocks are available, it doesn't return any row too.

Comment: That's the point. As I said, **if this does not return any result, perform the original query**

Comment: How to do that? Please help again.

Comment: With an if statement in your favorite programming language?

Comment: I am using php. But I still not got the idea of what you mean since the query above will always return no row in any condition.

Comment: it will return one row with the value "1" if there is any pair (up,oh) that matches the given conditions, i.e. where up.quantity is less than oh.quantity. Then you know that you don't have to execute the original query.

Comment: Well in one hand you are right (when I change `<` to `>`). But what if there is only one product which is asked and it is available. It will also return value "1" too.

Comment: Now I know what is the problem with the query above. When the product is not exist (NOT only the quantity) the query will return it as true.

Comment: I don't think so.. this is an inner join, if no row is found in the second table matching the join condition, you get no result.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query, this returns 0 if any of the products does not have enough quantity in stock:

```
SELECT  (SUM(CASE WHEN up.quantity >= oh.quantity THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)) AS inStock
        #up.quantity AS stockAble, oh.quantity AS stockAsk
FROM    stock_update up
JOIN    orders oh
ON      up.product_id = oh.product_id
#AND        up.quantity >= oh.quantity
WHERE   oh.reference_no = 12345;
```

Comment: How about the performance of this query. Because when I run this query on the page its result is not as accurate as if i run this on the workbench.

Comment: I'm sorry @klaudia, I don't understand how the query is not as accurate when run on the page as when run on the workbench. Does it gives different results? The performance will significantly depend on your database, indexes and so on. Here we are clearly leaving many constraints outside and focusing on your original problem. Hope this helps.